# How to get the parent function name of the function being called

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the name of the parent function of the function being called.

**For example if I have these functions:**

```
var functions = {

    coolfunction1: {
        add: function () {

        },
        delete: function () {

        },
        save: function () {

        }
    }, 

    coolfunction2: {
        add: function () {

            // i want to console.log() the name of the parent of this function,
            // output: coolfunction2

        },
        delete: function () {

        },
        save: function () {

        }
    }

}
```

When I call **`functions.coolfunction2.add()`**, is there a way to log the name of the parent function that was run?

I know I can use the variable **`this`** but that only outputs the names of the children functions, **`add()`**, **`delete()`**, **`save()`**.

How can I know that the **`coolfuntion2`** was run?

I know this can be done manually, by rewriting the function name in the **`add()`** function, but is there a way to get the name dynamically?

Comment: No, there is not. Consider doing `functions.ooops = functions.coolfunction2;` and then invoking `functions.oops.add()`, which name would you expect? Objects don't have a name, unless you hardcode it somewhere.

Comment: There are no parent functions in your code. "functions" is an object literal and so is "coolfunction1".

Answer (score 2):

You can add a getter to those methods as

```
Object.keys(functions).forEach(t =>
  Object.keys(functions[t]).forEach(t2 => {
    var func = functions[t][t2]; //save a reference to function since it won't be a function anymore once a getter is assigned
    Object.defineProperty(functions[t], t2, {
      get: function() {
        console.log(t); //print the name of parent property or grand-parent property, etc
        //func();
        return func; //return the reference to this function
      }
    });
  })
);
```

**Demo**

```js
var functions = {

  coolfunction1: {
    add: function() {

    },
    delete: function() {

    },
    save: function() {

    }
  },

  coolfunction2: {
    add: function() {

      console.log("a is invoked");

    },
    delete: function() {

    },
    save: function() {

    }
  }

};

Object.keys(functions).forEach(t =>
  Object.keys(functions[t]).forEach(t2 => {
    var func = functions[t][t2];
    Object.defineProperty(functions[t], t2, {
      get: function() {
        console.log(t);
        //func();
        return func;
      }
    });
  })
);

functions.coolfunction2.add();
functions.coolfunction2.add();
functions.coolfunction1.add();
```

Comment: My last remaining vote for today is for this answer. Very interesting solution